# BeanNameAutoProxyCreator on Grails 2 isn't working

Tags: java, groovy, log4j, grails-2.0, spring-aop

I want use `spring` and `log4jdbc` in Grails 2.2.1 to catch the jdbc info, but it isn't working and is returning an error.

Here is the `log4j` config in `config.groovy`:

```
info   'jdbc.sqlonly','jdbc.sqltiming';
```

Here is the Grails spring dsl (resourc.groovy):

```
beans = {
xmlns aop:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
aop{
    config("proxy-target-class":true)
}
log4jdbcInterceptor(net.sf.log4jdbc.DataSourceSpyInterceptor)
dataSourceLog4jdbcAutoProxyCreator(org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanNameAutoProxyCreator){
    interceptorNames ="log4jdbcInterceptor"
    beanNames = ["dataSource"]
}
```

And `DataSourceSpyInterceptor.java`

```
public class DataSourceSpyInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {
    private RdbmsSpecifics rdbmsSpecifics = null;
    private RdbmsSpecifics getRdbmsSpecifics(Connection conn) {
        if(rdbmsSpecifics == null) {
            rdbmsSpecifics = DriverSpy.getRdbmsSpecifics(conn);
        }
        return rdbmsSpecifics;
    }
    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
        Object result = invocation.proceed();
        if(SpyLogFactory.getSpyLogDelegator().isJdbcLoggingEnabled()) {
            if(result instanceof Connection) {
                Connection conn = (Connection)result;
                return new ConnectionSpy(conn,getRdbmsSpecifics(conn));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```